# Suppose $f:R^n \to R$ is differentiable. Let $d\in R^n$ with $∥d∥ = 1,$ show that $⟨∇f (x), d⟩ ≥ −∥∇f (x)∥.$

Tags: optimization, vector-analysis

Suppose $f:R^n \to R$ is differentiable. Let $d\in R^n$ with $∥d∥ = 1,$ show that

$⟨∇f (x), d⟩ ≥ −∥∇f (x)∥.$

For what $d$ does the equality hold?

My solution so far, please let me know if it is correct and let me know if I have potential mistakes.

$⟨∇f (x), d⟩=∇f (x)^Td=\sum_{i=1}^n∇f (x_i)d_i=\frac{df}{dx_1}d_1+\frac{df}{dx_2}d_2+...+\frac{df}{dx_n}d_n$

$∥∇f (x)∥$=$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n∇f (x_i)^2}=\sqrt{(\frac{df}{dx_1})^2+(\frac{df}{dx_2})^2+...+(\frac{df}{dx_n})^2}$

$\frac{df}{dx_1}d_1+\frac{df}{dx_2}d_2+...+\frac{df}{dx_n}d_n\geq-\sqrt{(\frac{df}{dx_1})^2+(\frac{df}{dx_2})^2+...+(\frac{df}{dx_n})^2}$

This equality holds for $d\ge0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cauchy Schwarz, $|\langle\nabla f(x),d\rangle|\leq \|\nabla f(x)\|$. This implies that $-\langle\nabla f(x),d\rangle\leq \|\nabla f(x)\|$ and $\langle \nabla f(x),d\rangle\geq -\|\nabla f(x)\|$.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't able to see how to apply the Cauchy Schwartz inequality, would it be possible to provide a bit more detail? Also for which $d$ does this inequality hold?

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz: $|\left<\nabla f(x),d\right>|\leq\|\nabla f(x)\|\|d\|=\|\nabla f(x)\|$.

Comment: @user284331 thank you!